# How to customize the author page in wordpress?

Tags: pages, author, author-template

Actually am getting the author URL by `get_author_posts_url($authorID)` 
It is redirecting to some page like http://example.com/members/authorName/

So on this page, I need to do some extra modification, couldn't figure out which template.page to edit. 
I searched `author-template` in wp-includes but did not find a way to customize the page.

So please guide me how to customize that page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to answer without looking at the codebase of your theme. You may need to edit the author.php file. If that file does not exist in your theme, look for the next file in the hierarchy. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#author-display

Comment: suggesting to look at `author.php` file is the answer, now am able to do what I need.